# Assigning a value at void pointer via lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest, googlemock

In my gtest, I want to populate content "outBuffer":

```
stDriverNotify* notifyData = new stDriverNotify;
notifyData->NotifyType = eDriverNotify_InputRedirect; 

EXPECT_CALL(*hidDeviceMock_, DeviceControl(_, _, _, _, _, _, _))
  .WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&](ULONG control, PVOID inBuffer, ULONG inSize, 
      PVOID outBuffer, ULONG outSize, PULONG bytesReturned, LPOVERLAPPED ov)
      {
         *bytesReturned = 32;
         outBuffer = notifyData;
         return E_FAIL;
      }));
```

However, notifyData's notifyType was not updated to eDriverNotify_InputRedirect.  Do you understand why?

I also tried this:

```
stDriverNotify notifyData;
notifyData.NotifyType = eDriverNotify_InputRedirect; 

EXPECT_CALL(*hidDeviceMock_, DeviceControl(_, _, _, _, _, _, _))
  .WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&](ULONG control, PVOID inBuffer, ULONG inSize, 
      PVOID outBuffer, ULONG outSize, PULONG bytesReturned, LPOVERLAPPED ov)
      {
         *bytesReturned = 32;
         outBuffer = &notifyData;
         return E_FAIL;
      }));
```

But also does not reflect the new value.  bytesReturned looks okay.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We can't tell what you doing wrong, since we don't know what all these parameters mean. `notifyData` address assignment to `outBuffer` doesn't look like correct code, since this is usual pointer, not pointer to pointer for example, so you can't return `notifyData` that way. *Probably* what you need is to copy content of `notifyData` to `outBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to make it work now..

It looks like void pointer cannot be assigned directly since it does not have a 'real' type.  So I assigned a value by using memcpy and casting inside the lambda:

```
memcpy((stDriverNotify*)outBuffer, &notifyData, sizeof(stDriverNotify));
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type - assigning to a (value) parameter has no effect outside the function, regardless of the parameter's type. Note that you're solving the problem by avoiding assignment altogether, and if `stDriverNotify` is not a trivially copyable type the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: `*((stDriverNotify*)outBuffer) = notifyData;` is much better for readability and doesn't have problems with non-trivial/non-POD types.